# Identification of a Lenovo W530 fan connector type

Tags: identification, connector, fan, laptop

I have been trying to identify the black connector in the picture. It is from an older Lenovo W530 laptop fan made by Delta. Unfortunately it appears Delta doesn't have a data sheet (I asked them) and the same part number comes with different connectors (or Lenovo custom ordered, modified, etc...). It doesn't appear to be the normal fan connector type I've seen before.

I obtained a Delta fan with the same Delta part number, but it has the white connector which is not a fit. I've gone through some of the connector id sites, but there are sooo many different ones and I haven't been able to find it. Hoping someone sees the black connector in the pic and can identify the family it belongs to?
Black connector is ~ 6mmx2.5mm and 3mm tall (not sure what the right terminology is...3mm from where the wires are inserted to the face that inserts into the board)

[image: Connector Black is the one I need to identify]

Have done a bunch of JST type connections in the past, so not a novice on crimping and such, but I need to identify the black connector type so I can get the materials to switch the new fan from white to black.

Thanks so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Hirose, maybe DF3, maybe

Comment: What are the dimensions?  Could be a Molex PicoBlade.

Comment: The black connector is ~ 6mmx2.5mm and 3mm tall. Will add to the main description

Comment: What’s the pin-pin pitch?

Comment: Hard to measure (at least for me) Winny but appears to me ~1.2mm pin-to-pin

Comment: Pretty sure it isn't DF3 after checking the datasheet, but thanks for the pointer Tyler. So far Picoblade looks closest based on their datasheet, thanks Vir. Will take the fan out later tonight and measure properly out in the open with a caliper to verify.

Comment: if you put a scale in the photo with the connector people can count pixels an get an accurate measurement.

Comment: Why not cut and splice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for all the feedback folks...awesome response to my first EE stackexchange question!

After removing the fan and measuring with a caliper under a magnifier, then digging through the datasheets from the suggestions, the black connector is almost certainly a

Molex 510210400 1.25mm Pitch, PicoBlade Receptacle Crimp Housing, Single Row, Friction Lock, 4 Circuits

The measurements and profile match exactly with the datasheet

@Vir is a steely eyed electroman!

Answer (score 1):

You did not give us the pitch of the black connector, but I will guess 1.5 mm.

My [Connector Identification Utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_w2b_conn_1p5) lists these connectors:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - 15SH + 15CH
- JST - CZ + CZH
- JST - ZH
- Molex - Pico-SPOX
- TE - HP-1.5
- Wurth - WR-WTB 648

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that's a [JST connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector).

If you measured 1.2mm pin pitch, my guess is that it's actually 1.25mm and what you want is a JST-GH connector. There's also JST-ZH at 1.5mm pitch.